# Django Environment Variables is not recognized

Tags: python, django, staging

Going through a tutorial at [Obey The Testing Goat](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_manual_deployment.html) and I'm getting errors using environmental variables. Using Django 1.11, Selenium 3, and Python 3.6.

```
(py36) C:\testgoat\superlists>STAGING_SERVER=superlists-staging.ottg.eu python manage.py test functional_tests
'STAGING_SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I understand the tutorial correctly, an environmental variable, `STAGING_SERVER`, is used run tests using a real server instead of Django's test server.

```
django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
import unittest
import sys
import os

MAX_WAIT = 10

class NewVisitorTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        staging_server = os.environ.get('STAGING_SERVER')
        if staging_server:
            setattr(self, 'live_server_url', 'http://' + staging_server)

    [...]
```

Comment: Windows shell doesn't support environment variables like that. It might work on shells like bash, but not cmd.

Comment: Is there an equivalent method of doing this on Windows? Also I am running this through Anaconda if that means anything.

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt